# How to limit text to 3 sentences only?

Tags: php

I will have a $content variable, with unlimited number of text (can be any number of sentences, and paragraphs)

Every sentence in English ends, with either dot, ellypses, question mark, or exclamation mark, so these could be:

```
$dot = ".";
$ellypses = "...";
$question = "?";
$exclamation = "!";
```

What I am trying to achieve is limit $content to the first three sentences only, and get it displayed on a blog. This would mean that any combination of these (any instance) would need to be recognized, "counted to three", and than stored in another variable, which could be called $shortened_text (it does not have to be printed on a page, I will be using this with CyberSeo plugin for Wordpress).

Would you be able to suggest how to write a code for something like this (and if not possible, what php functions I should use)?

Comment: English isn't that simple. Given the algorithm you describe, Mr. Smith, you would reject this three sentence comment. Do you see the problem?

Comment: As @Quentin points out, it's not that simple. I'd suggest just limiting it to a specific number of characters and adding ellipses to make it obvious the content has been cut short. This also avoids the problem of there being the possibility of very, very long sentences.

Comment: This is true. I did not thing about it. It could be better to limit each string to, lets say 75 words, and shorten it at the end of last sentence (going forward, so it could be a little longer than this). I've seen a similar code on this site. I will look into it.

Comment: `preg_match('~^\s*(?:[A-Z].{10,100}?(?:\.|\.\.\.|\?|\!)\s+){1,3}~s', $content, $m)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do a subsequence search ([`strstr()` in PHP allows for this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php)). Try implementing this pseudocode:

```
set $n equal to 3
if $content content contains $n occurrences of ("?" or "!" or "..."):
     set $someFlag = True  // this is just whatever flag  you set to indicate that three sentences have been inputted
else if $content contains $n occurrences of "." and they are not "...":
     set $someFlag = True
```

You could concatenate both of those branch statements into a single `if` connected by an `OR`, too.

EDIT: you can make this easier using [`substr_count()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr-count.php).